# Can the content in Alloy Controller.getView() can be updated?

Tags: view, controller, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am using Alloy 1.3. Can the content in the Controller.getView() can be updated? For example:

In Alloy, if we have view view.xml

```
<Alloy>
   <View>
      <Label id="label1"/>
      ... other content ...
   </View>
</Alloy>
```

In view.js

```
exports.updateLabel = function(value){
   $.label1.text = value;
}
```

If I have another controller e.g. index.js

```
var v = Alloy.createController('view').getView();
// assume $.win is the <Window> in index.xml
$.win.add(v);

function updateContent(value){
   // This is not work. I want to know how it can be updated 
   // after the controller turned into a view
   v.updateLabel(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating content on object returned from controller.getView() method is fine. In your view.js example you can change label1 text in two different ways:

```
exports.updateLabel = function(value){
   $.label1.text = value;
}
```

or

```
exports.updateLabel = function(value){
   $.getView('label1').text = value;
}
```

If you are calling $.getView() without any parameters it will return top level view which has the same id as name of your controller and view.

Comment: In the index.js, I cannot find updateLabel. When break in the index.js file, v.updateLabel is undefined